# メインプロセスが終了したときにサブプロセスも自動終了させたい

Tags: c#, .net

`Process.Start()` でサブプロセスを作っています。通常はメインプロセスからサブプロセスの寿命を管理しているのですが、メインプロセスが異常終了した場合にサブプロセスが残ってしまいます。

Q1. メインプロセスが終了したときにサブプロセスも自動的に終了させる設定はありますでしょうか。

Q2. 自動終了させる設定がないとしたら、このサブプロセスを終了させるのはどのようにするのがセオリーでしょうか。

---

- Windows10 64bit
- .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: 参考までにサブプロセスにわける理由は何でしょうか？ プロセスを分けないのがセオリーだと思いますので。

Comment: 64bitアプリで32bitネイティブdllを使用することを実現するためです。32bitサブプロセスで32bitネイティブdllを読み込み、64bitメインプロセスからプロセス間通信でアクセスすることで実現したいと考えています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. 私の知る限り、.NET Frameworkの範囲で設定はありません。

A2. PinvokeでWindows APIを呼び出すことになると思います。
大まかな処理の流れは下記のようになると思います。

---

1. `CreateJobObject` 関数でジョブオブジェクトを作成する。
2. `SetInformationJobObject`関数で `JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION::LimitFlags` に `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` を設定する。
3. `AssignProcessToJobObject`関数でジョブに子プロセスを紐付ける。
4. 子プロセスが必要な期間、ジョブオブジェクトのハンドルを保持する。(開放しなければプロセス終了時に開放される)

---

GitHubのMicrosoftのリポジトリだと、[ProcessJobObject.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/blob/7b6248203164f8ea821f6795632bd22e0b69afb0/src/DataCollectors/TraceDataCollector/ProcessJobObject.cs)が参考になると思います。

Comment: [Managing Processes in Jobs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/job-objects#managing-processes-in-jobs)によるとJobに関連付けられたプロセスが`CreateProcess`で子プロセスを作成した場合、子プロセスは自動的にJobに関連付けられるそうです。3.は子プロセスでもいいですが、自プロセスにするのも一つの手かもしれません。

Comment: @sayuri 確かに自プロセスをジョブに組み込むほうが、子プロセス起動毎に`AssignProcessToJobObject` 関数を呼び出さずに済むので、場合によっては手間が少なくなりますね。勉強になりました。